# How can I concatenate video clips with ffmpeg without causing audio de-sync?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to automate the trimming and concatenation of video clips that also contain audio using ffmpeg. The following commands are being used to trim clips and then concatenate the trimmed clips.

`.\ffmpeg -ss $startInSeconds -i $inputFile -t $partDurationInSeconds $outputFile`

This is done once per input file, the values of $startInSeconds and $partDurationInSeconds are different for different clips.

`.\ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i .\list.txt -c copy $concatOutputFile`

list.txt is a list of $outputFile from the first trim command.

The audio of the concat video file gradually de-syncs over time (slowing down compared to the trimmed clips), which is the problem I'm looking to fix. It seems to slow down by about half a frame at each concat join.

Why is the concat command causing this de-sync and what can I do about it?

I thought this was due to a mismatch in duration between the audio and video tracks of a trimmed clip (the audio would often be shorter than the video after trimming). I then tried padding the audio to match the video before concatenating but the problem persists. I also found an example where the tracks were identical in length and the problem persists, so I think the concat command is the culprit, not the trim command.

Comment: I think that the `-c copy` is the main cause for the de-sync. Instead of creating intermediate files, and concatenate them later, it is recommended to use `inpoint` and `outpoint` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42750147/4926757). Using `-c copy` prevents re-encoding, and prevents cutting and merging the audio and video streams accurately. Select codecs like `-c:v libx264 -c:a aac` instead of `-c copy` (or just remove `-c copy`) for re-encoding. Re-encoding reduces the quality, but there is probably no alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I ended up using another program called sox to extract the audio at the same timestamps that ffmpeg was trimming the video, then combining them with ffmpeg. Concating these clips then doesn't have the audio sync issue.